# Overriding a virtual function of a nested class

Tags: c++, function, class, overriding, virtual

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Base {
public:
    class Nested {
        virtual void display() {
            std::cout << "Not overridden" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    Nested N;
};
```

And I have another class named `Derived` that inherits from the class `Base`.

Is it possible to override the `display()` method declared inside the `Nested` so that in the `Derived` class it does this instead:

```
void display() {
    std::cout << "Overridden" << std::endl;
}
```

If so, how?

If not, what other options do I have?

Comment: No, that's not possible, these classes are completely independent besides the nesting relationship.

Comment: Since `Base` does not have a method called `display`, it's unclear what you expect anything that's derived from `Base` to override.

Comment: The`Nested N` would have to be polymorphic (a pointer or reference, the smart pointer `std::unique_ptr<Nested>` would be a good choice here) and then the Derived would have to replace N with an instance of `Derived::DerivedNested` instead of `Base::Nested`

Comment: Have a look at C++ iostreams, where an `fstream` causes the `streambuf` member in `iostream` to become a `filebuf` which is derived from `streambuf`.  Hint: the base class actually uses a pointer, and `streambuf` declares virtual members which `filebuf` overrides.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've yet to familiarize myself with pointers, if it's not an inconvenience, could you write an answer with a short example explaining what you said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested class (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)):

> The name of the nested class exists in the scope of the enclosing class, and name lookup from a member function of a nested class visits the scope of the enclosing class after examining the scope of the nested class. Like any member of its enclosing class, the nested class has access to all names (private, protected, etc) to which the enclosing class has access, but it is otherwise independent and has no special access to the this pointer of the enclosing class.

and since c++11

> Declarations in a nested class can use any members of the enclosing class, following the usual usage rules for the non-static members.

So sloppy speaking, nesting classes is about names and accessing members. Thats it.

A class deriving from `Base` does not inherit a method `display`, because `Base` has no method `display`. Concerning inheriting from `Base` there is little difference to:

```
class Nested {
    virtual void display() {
        std::cout << "Not overridden" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Base {
public:
   Nested N;
};

class Derived : public Base {};
```

`Derived` inherits the member `N`, but no methods, because `Base` has no methods (apart from the special compiler generated ones).

Comment: "A class inheriting from Base does not inherit the nested class."  Sure it does. Unqualified lookup of `Nested` inside of `Derived` will happily find `Base::Nested`.  What it doesn't do is create a separate type `Derived::Nested` which is inherited from `Base::Nested`, and although that's easy enough to do, `Base`'s member `N` won't use it.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, get it. Thats poor wording, I think I can just remove that sentence