# Subclass a class to change an inner classes virtual function without reimplementing the outside class

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308346/overriding-a-virtual-function-of-a-nested-class) which asks how to override a virtual function in a nested class. However, while answered, I still haven't understood how to achieve something like that.

```
class Base {
public:
    class Nested {
        virtual void display() {
            std::cout << "Not overridden" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    
    /* tons of functionality which makes use of Nested and its methods */
};
```

Take this example code:
I would like to implement a variant `ImprovedBase`, which only changes the behaviour of the `display` function (ideally add something and then call the original implementation) while basically keeping the functionality inherited from `Base` intact **without reimplementing `Base`'s code which is dependent on `Nested`**.

This structure is part of a library, so I am unable to modify `Base`/`Nested` themselves.

(How) can I implement this?

Comment: `struct ImprovedBase : Base { struct ImprovedNested : Base::Nested { void display() override { std::cout << "Overridden\n"; } }; };`  Keep in mind that "inner classes" are only contained in the outer class from a namespace perspective.  They don't have any other implicit relationship.

Comment: There is (almost) nothing special about a "nested" class in C++; you do it the same way as if it were defined outside `Base`. (So if `Base` relies specifically on `Nested`, you can pretty much give up now.)

Comment: Okay so this is basically what I have, but how does this help me? When I use the functions inherited from the `Base` that use `Nested` from `ImprovedBase` (since this `Nested`  class just sits in the namespace and doesn't have any other link), they will in turn use the implementation from the original `Nested`, rather than `ImprovedNested` will they not?
EDIT: I just saw your comment @molbdnilo - great, thank you :) Frustrating, but I'll just dirty-patch the library and be sad.

Comment: "will they not?" the inheritance works the same here as it works without nested classes. When `tons of methods` use `Nested` then that is `Nested` not something derived from nested. Thats how inheritance works. The issue is not with how inheritance works on nested classes but in your desire to use inheritance. This is a XY problem. You should show an example for `tons of functionality`, my guess is that you want to make `Base` a class template to easily switch the implementation

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai if you're really interested in my particular use case: I am trying to use the `live555` library and use the `RTSPServer` class, but inject something into the `handleCmd_...` methods. So yeah, ideally I would like `Base` to be something easily editable, but since I am relying on library code, this is not something I have control over (+ what I am trying to insert is like 3 lines of code, so its not worth overengineering)

Comment: How `Nested` is used/constructed? Is there a place to substitutes with another class? (`Base` doesn't have to change normally).

Comment: I am not sure if I am interested in your specific use case ;).  Someone suggested the straighforward answer, but you rejected it, now I am trying to see why this is not a solution. I also wrote an answer, but also there I am just guessing what you actually need. In your question you only write about your attempted solution, but the heart of the problem you want to solve is hidden behind a vague comment

Comment: my point is just that you can inherit from `Nested` in a class that inherits from `Base`. That does answer your question taken literally, but as you realize in the comment, it isnt helping to avoid the code duplication

Comment: @tistorm Inherit from `RTSPServer` and override `createNewClientConnection` to return an object with your desired behaviour.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I appreciate your help, maybe my actual question isn't perfect in expressing what I want. What I've taken from your answer and the other comment is that I _can_ override a virtual function in a Nested class, but I _cannot_ change the inner class implementation of a base class without also duplicating the code from base.
I'll try to edit the question to reflect this :)

Comment: @molbdnilo This is exactly what I was looking for - now that you mention it, it seems easy. Thank your for the tailored advice

Comment: Depending on how exactly `Nested` is used, it may be entirely impossible to do this. You haven't shown enough info about how the `Nested` class is used to decide, if may be possible to do this. E.g. in the following case it's impossible do this: `class A
{
public:
    struct B
    {
        virtual void f() = 0;
    };

    struct C : B
    {
        void f()
        {
        }
    };

    struct D : B { void f() { } };

    A(bool b)
        : m_b(b ? (B*) new C : new D)
    {}

    void f() { m_b->f(); }
private: std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};`

Answer (score 2):

Nesting classes often come with lots of unfulfilled expectations. Often they create problems that would not be present if the classes were not nested.

I cannot tell why you used a nested class in the first place, but lets assume you would be fine with not nesting them:

```
struct Nested {
    virtual void display() {
        std::cout << "Not overridden" << std::endl;
    }
};
  
struct Base {
    Nested example;
    void other_example(const Nested& n) { n.display(); }
};
```

If it was only about overriding `Nested::display` you would use inheritance. Any object that derives from `Nested` can be passed to `Base::other_example` and the console output can be customized. However, inheritance does not help a bit to "extend" functionality of the `Nested` member. Polymorphism requires pointers or references to work.

You can make `Base` a template to easily customize its behavior:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base {
    T example;
    void other_example(const T& n) { n.display(); }
};
```

Whether this is a viable approach depends on whether you need to treat `Base`s with different behavior to be polymorphic (though even then this might be an approach). While `Base<Nested>` is the same as above, you can now customize `T` as you like, for example:

```
 struct Foo {
     void display() { std::cout << "Hello World\n"; }
 };
```

Then `Base<Foo>` is a class with a `Foo` member and passing a `Foo` to `Base<Foo>::other_example` will print `Hello World` on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inherit from `Base` to provide derived class from `Nested`

You might simply do:

```
class ImprovedNested : Base::Nested
{
    void display() override
    {
        Base::Nested::display();
        std::cout << "Overridden" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Now, you have to provide your version instead of the original one.
and you don't show the code.

As `Nested` has `virtual` method, there is normally/probably way to pass our custom version.

With something like:

```
class Base
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Nested> nested = std::make_unique<Nested>();
public:
    void setNested(std::unique_ptr<Nested> value) { nested = std::move(value); }

    // ...
};
```

You might do:

```
Base base;
base.setNested(std::make_unique<ImprovedNested>());
// Use base normally now.
```